# What do you call this notion of similarity between subsets of a metric space?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Given a metric space $X$, we say a *continuous isometry* is a continuous map $F:X\times[0,1]\to X$ such that defining $f_t(x) = F(x,t)$ for $t \in [0,1]$, we have that $f_0$ is the identity map and $f_t$ is an isometry for each $t\in [0,1]$.

Given a metric space $X$ and $S,T\subset X$, we say $S\sim T$ if there is a continuous isometry $F$ where $f_1(S) = T$. We have that in the unit circle $S^1$, that $\{1, e^{i\pi/3},-1\} \not\sim \{1, e^{-i\pi/3},-1\}$, despite complex conjugation being an isometry which sends these sets to one another.

I was curious if this notion of similarity has a name, and if it has been studied before at least for certain spaces $X$. For example, are there any natural invariants for this similarity which completely determine finite sets?

Comment: [Ambient isotopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_isotopy) is related, except it doesn't require the maps to be isometric

Comment: It would not cause any harm to say $T$ is a rotation of $S$.  i.e. you are talking about the orbit of the path-component of the identity in the isometry group of $X$.   In euclidean space, that is rotations.  But you could be less casual and talk about the orbit of the path-component of the identity in $isom(X)$. This is for the compact-open topology on $isom(X)$.

Comment: By analogy from Euclidean geometry, you may call such map *motion* or *direct motion*; I would use the term *directly congruent* for the induced equivalence relation on the subset.

Comment: I would also call this a *motion* (or perhaps an *isometric motion*) of a metric space. Calling the equivalence relation on subsets *direct congruence* or perhaps *ambiently isometric* also sounds about right.